# Can a "Standard" WCF service and a REST-ful OData service be combined into a single service?

Tags: wcf, hosting, odata

I have a WCF service that offers a standard SOAP interface over TCP/IP, HTTP or Named Pipes. This service computes and caches a large, complex, relational data set and offers views on it to clients, via high-level service operations. It's working perfectly.

I also have a separate custom OData service that offers the underlying data in a more "raw" form. This service shares some of the plumbing of the first, with respect to loading and caching the large, complex, relational data set, but is otherwise a standalone service that can be hosted apart from the first.

I'm currently hosting the standard SOAP service in IIS with Windows Process Activation Services, and I'm sure I can do the same thing with the OData service, as a separate endpoint.

If I wanted to host them together in the same IIS host process, what are my options for allowing the two services to share the underlying cached data set, to save on load time and memory consumption?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can deal with the limitations of the [Reflection Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723653.aspx) or are willing to deal with the complexity of a [Custom Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee960143.aspx), you should be able to construct a caching layer that makes the same data available to both your WCF service and your WCF Data Service.

(This would also technically work with the Entity Framework provider, but it sounds like that might not be a good fit for your other needs.)

I can post a sample if you run into trouble getting it up and running.

Comment: Mark, my data service is indeed a custom provider that dynamically serves up the metadata and resources of the underlying dataset, and shares a lower-level API with the "standard" service, for loading and caching the data. The only problem is that currently they each use that lower-level library to separately load and cache the data. This is fine if the two services are hosted on separate servers, but I'd like to optimize away the additional overhead when both services are on the same server (in the same w3wp instance).

Comment: The trouble I'm having is getting the two to co-exist in the same WAS-hosted service, so that they can share the underlying cached data structures. The biggest issue I have right now is that there seems to be no way for the data service to support impersonation (which is required by the "standard" service). I'd be happy to share more info offline, and would appreciate any help you could give.